# Diameter request is not received by seagull server

Tags: erlang, 4g, diameter-protocol

I have an erlang client and seagull server for testing Sy-interface.

Capability exchange is done properly and tested by pcaps. When I send `SLR` using 
`diameter:call(?SERVICE_NAME, ?APP_ALIAS, SLR, [])`

`prepare_request` is called when I call server function for sending `SLR`. it returns `ok`

Erlang client keep sending Watchdog request.
But this is not received by seagull server. What are possible scenarios for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are possible scenario for Sy interface I've found in [Github](https://github.com/cgrates/cgrates/issues/1256).

Because I cannot have your environment so I just give you some advices base on my experience with seagull open source.

1. Can you re-check that your Erlang client which simulated PCRF send SLR msg to exactly OCS (IP, port,...) is correct or not? Use wireshack to check that. Sometime, PCRF send to 8003:TCP but OCS just use 8004:UDP.
2. Erlang client keep sending Watchdog request that seems PCRF still wait reply from OCS, did you reply PCRF with SLA msg? You can use the scenario in github I provided above

Comment: 1) `IP,Port` are ok.
2) Yes, I have `SLA` in seagull server, but it doesnt receive `SLR`

Comment: Did you run your scenario and catch up by wireshack ? Could you give me pcap file  and list PCRF and OCS addresses for me ? and SLR, SLA that you have sent ?

Comment: sorry, its not my private project. I can not give you addresses or pcap. But `CER/CEA` is successful with proper source and destination parameters for `SLR`

Comment: Did you use the real SLR msg or just created by yourself? Avp in SLR sometime co-working. Moreover, maybe seagull server is closed socket during that time => set alive time socket. There are a huge reasons why seagull cannot receive. Because of less information, I cannot predict more.

Comment: Yes, its proper `SLR`, defined in dictionary file and rebar3 generates `.hrl` and `.erl` for `ts_29_219`